# How get enum attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I creating template editor.

```
@model dynamic


@{
    var modelMetadata = Html.GetModelMetadataFor(model => model);
    var selectList = ReflectionHelpers.GetSelectListByEnumFor(modelMetadata);
    String name = //get property name;
}
```

with get modelMetadata all right

But how get attributes I don't understand.

Before I use this code:

```
Type enumType = GetNonNullableModelType(metadata);
IEnumerable<TEnum> values = Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<TEnum>();

IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = values.Select(value =>
    new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = GetEnumDescription(value),
        Value = value.ToString(),
        Selected = value.Equals(metadata.Model)
    });
```

But in this time I don't understand how take TEnum

My question is: "How create select list from enum"

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Could you provide an example of model and how is this template intended to be used?

Comment: this is UIHint for enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom html helper which will generate a dropdown list for the current model (assuming this model is an enum of course):

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString DropDownListForEnum(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        var model = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model;
        if (model == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("You must have a model in order to use this method");
        }
        var enumType = model.GetType();
        if (!enumType.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("This method works only with enum types.");
        }

        var fields = enumType.GetFields(
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Public
        );
        var values = Enum.GetValues(enumType).OfType<object>();
        var items =
            from value in values
            from field in fields
            let descriptionAttribute = field
                .GetCustomAttributes(
                    typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true
                )
                .OfType<DescriptionAttribute>()
                .FirstOrDefault()
            let description = (descriptionAttribute != null)
                ? descriptionAttribute.Description
                : value.ToString()
            where value.ToString() == field.Name
            select new { Id = value, Name = description };

        var selectList = new SelectList(items, "Id", "Name", model);
        return htmlHelper.DropDownList("", selectList);
    }
}
```

and then in your template simply call this helper:

```
@Html.DropDownListForEnum()
```

---

UPDATE:

And if you wanted to have all the code in the template you could also do that:

```
@using System.ComponentModel
@using System.Reflection
@using System.Linq;
@model object

@{
    var model = Html.ViewData.Model;
    if (model == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("You must have a model in order to use this template");
    }
    var enumType = model.GetType();
    if (!enumType.IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("This method works only with enum types.");
    }

    var fields = enumType.GetFields(
        BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Public
    );
    var values = Enum.GetValues(enumType).OfType<object>();
    var items =
        from value in values
        from field in fields
        let descriptionAttribute = field
            .GetCustomAttributes(
                typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true
            )
            .OfType<DescriptionAttribute>()
            .FirstOrDefault()
        let description = (descriptionAttribute != null)
            ? descriptionAttribute.Description
            : value.ToString()
        where value.ToString() == field.Name
        select new { Id = value, Name = description };

    var selectList = new SelectList(items, "Id", "Name", model);
}

@Html.DropDownList("", selectList)
```

Comment: Yes yes, I this can too. But I need separately all get. selectlist, property name, and create drop down list.

Comment: You want to do everything in the template?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i don't know how asp.net works, but within .Net framework i use this extension method:

```
public static IList<KeyValuePair<T, string>> ToList<T>() where T : struct
{
    var type = typeof(T);

    if (!type.IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enum");
    }

    return (IList<KeyValuePair<T, string>>)
            Enum.GetValues(type)
                .OfType<T>()
                .Select(e =>
                {
                    var asEnum = (Enum)Convert.ChangeType(e, typeof(Enum));
                    return new KeyValuePair<T, string>(e, GetEnumDescription(asEnum));
                })
                .ToArray();
}
```

Within winforms i can use it for a combo box by simply calling:

```
var pairs = EnumExtension.ToList<ContenAlignment>();
comboBoxFormat.DataSource = pairs;
comboBoxFormat.ValueMember = "Key";
comboBoxFormat.DisplayMember = "Value";
```

Maybe you can alter the above combo box code to your needs within asp.net.